# I need to make an array of five background colors and then use the "stylize() function" to select one at random for a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am in a basic HTML/JavaSript class and I can't figure out a way (and where to put) an array of five bgcolors and "use the stylize() function to select one of the colors to pick the cell background at random".  I have to use and edit the code below.  The code already works, I just need to add the array of bgcolors and use it to change the table cell bgcolor. I am new to HTML and JavaScript and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, in advance!

```
<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<link href="capstone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script>
var index = 0;

function stylize()
{
  index++;
  if (index > 20) index =1;
  var s = "myStyle" + index;
  var e = document.getElementById("MessageText");
  e.className = s;
  setTimeout("stylize()", 1500);
  return;
}

function getRandomInt (min, max) 
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

index = getRandomInt(1, 20);

 </script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="stylize()">
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
     <div id="MessageText" class="myStyle1">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

</html>
```

HERE IS MY CSS PAGE:

```
.myStyle1 {font-family:Impact; color:black; font-size:100}
.myStyle2 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:18}
.myStyl31 {font-family:Tahoma; color:black; font-size:24}
.myStyle4 {font-family:Verdana; color:black; font-size:48}
.myStyle5 {font-family:Impact; color:red; font-size:30}
.myStyle6 {font-family:Marlett; color:green; font-size:65}
.myStyle7 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:46}
.myStyle8 {font-family:Courier Sans MS Bold; color:blue; font-size:60}
.myStyle9 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35}
.myStyle10 {font-family:Arial Italic; color:blue; font-size:10}
.myStyle11 {font-family:Times New Roman; color:blue; font-size:50}
.myStyle12 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:38}
.myStyle13 {font-family:Verdana; color:white; font-size:30}
.myStyle14 {font-family:Marlett; color:blue; font-size:70}
.myStyle15 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:24}
.myStyle16 {font-family:Georgia; color:blue; font-size:24}
.myStyle17 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35}
.myStyle18 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:12;}
.myStyle19 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:20;}
.myStyle20 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:55}
```

Comment: I'm sure many here can answer this just fine but it wouldn't teach you anything. Look up CSS color syntax (you can make your own colors...) and here's a good Javascript reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `background-color` rule to each of those classes and you should be good to go, giving people migraines for no reason at all, just because you can. SWEET!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it has to pick a css class at random and then seperatly pick a cell background color at random....

Comment: Well, you could define classes for the background colours, and then use `e.className = "myStyle"+index+" myBackground"+bgindex;` in a similar way to what you have now.